# Integral of Time-delay System

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The following is a part from *Stability of Time-delay System* by Gu, Keqin, Jie Chen, and Vladimir L. Kharitonov.

[image: Problem Description]

I have 2 questions:

(1) First question:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
x(t)=e^{a_0 t} x(0) + \int_0^t e^{a_0(t-u)}[a_1 x(u-r)+h(u)] \, du
\end{equation}
from
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\dot{x}(t)=a_0x(t)+a_1x(t-r)+h(t)
\end{equation}

(2) Second question:

How to understand equation (\ref{1}) in an intuitive way so that next time when I encounter this kind of differential-difference equation like equation (1.7) I can easily write out the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the first question. However, anyone is appreciated and welcome to provide a better/easier solution than mime.

Equation (2) can be rewritten into:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t) - a_0x(t) = a_1x(t-r) + h(t) \\
\Rightarrow e^{-a_0t}[\dot{x}(t) - a_0x(t)] = e^{-a_0t}[a_1x(t-r) + h(t) ] \\
\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}[e^{-a_0 t}x(t)] = e^{-a_0t}[a_1x(t-r) + h(t) ] \\
\Rightarrow \int_0^t \frac{d}{du}[e^{-a_0 u}x(u)] du = \int_0^t e^{-a_0 u}[a_1x(u-r) + h(u)]du \\
\Rightarrow e^{-a_0 t}x(t)-x(0) = \int_0^t e^{-a_0 u}[a_1x(u-r) + h(u)]du \\
\Rightarrow x(t) =e^{a_0 t} x(0) + \int_0^t e^{a_0(t-u)}[a_1 x(u-r)+h(u)] \, du
\end{equation}